# I am not able to access my admin in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite

I have Ubuntu VM with Apache Server on which i am running my application. I have inserted some login and registration file using Filezilla.

But my registration, Login and admin page is not working. It is giving me

```
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: attempt to write a readonly database
```

I tried the following after doing some Stackoveflow.
`chown root db.sqlite3`. Unfortunately, I still get the same error when trying to access above page. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Probably something to do with changing user permission which i have no idea where to start in diagnosing what permission issue is going on.

**Edit:**

After giving the ownership to Apache User I am able to fix this issue.
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `database` is set to **read-only** permission. You have to give write permission to your `sqlite3 db`. you can use the `chmod` command for changing the file permission

`sudo chmod 666 db.sqlite3` ( For read and write permission to every user).

6 indicates read and write permission(4+2)

- Read -------> 4
- Write -------> 2
- Execute ---> 1